# Silverlight DataGrid and Binding columns

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I have a silverlight datagrid control and columns autogenerate property is set to false.
I am using MVVM and wants to bind the columns collection.

The data which i get is from xml. Something similar to sample code

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140525195434/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deepak_verma/archive/2008/07/19/dynamic-creation-binding-of-silverlight-datagrid.aspx)

Now by passing the datagrid control from xmal file to the modelview I can get the expected behavior but with that way , i am adding columns in the datagrid control.

Is there any way, so that I can bind the columns collection with the datagrid control so that no need to pass the control to view model.

-Rajesh

Comment: Just a personal opinion, but IMVHO your viewmodel should not know about grid columns - it should just present a list of tabular data or objects, and it is up to the View to decide how to present it - the view should not be getting any column info from the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a strange implementation of MVVM you have there.  Your ViewModel should be completely independent of the View.  If you want to create dynamic columns on the grid then why not expose a relevant property collection on the ViewModel, and iterate through it in a relevant method on the View code behind e.g.

```
//Used with an Infragistics XamWebGrid control
private void BuildGrid() {
    foreach (var dataItem in **ViewModel**.MyDataCollection)
    {
        var myCol = new TemplateColumn
        {
          HeaderText = dataItem.ItemNm,
          Key = dataItem.PrimaryKey
        };

        MyGrid.Columns.Add(myCol);
    }
}
```

You really shouldn't be passing controls from the View over to the ViewModel.  The ViewModel should have no knowledge of any controls on the View.